# Write query without join and using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to rewrite the join query with sub-query like `IN()`, `ANY()` operator.

Data set:

```
*categories*
categoryID name 
         5 ROD    
         7 CEMENT 

*products*
productID categoryID name      
        7          5 BSRM 10mm 
        9          5 KSRM 5mm  
       10          5 Julius    
       11          7           
       12          5 BSRM 25mm 

*sale_products*   
saleID productID 
   118         9 
   119         9 
   120         9 
   121         9 
   122        12 
   123        12 
   124        12
```

This is my query to read saleID, product name and category name for which already have sold.
[image]

My query is:

```
SELECT sale_products.saleID, products.name, categories.name
FROM categories
  INNER JOIN (products, sale_products)
    ON  categories.categoryID = products.categoryID
    AND products.productID = sale_products.productID
```

Now I want to the result set without join and with the sub-query methodology.

I try in this way:

```
SELECT categories.name
FROM categories
WHERE categories.categoryID IN
          (SELECT products.categoryID
           FROM products
           WHERE products.productID in
               (SELECT sale_products.productID FROM sale_products))
```

this query only give me the category name but I need also saleID, product name.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Why do you think that rewriting your query with subqueries will increase the performance of the query? Do you have performance issues at this moment with your existing version? If yes, then pls share the create table statements for the 3 tables and the results of the explain for your query with us and we will try to help.

Comment: As I know, we can replace joining tables query with nested sub-query. Some times for big data set it is time consuming to use join method and in this situation nested sub-query can help to speed up performance. So, I want to rewrite the join query using nested sub-query.

Comment: It is unlikely that any performance benefit will be afforded by use of a subquery here.

Comment: You can replace `inner join` with `left join` which is faster.

Comment: @Evgeny Assuming that there is a 1:1 correlation, then there is no difference in performance. If the LEFT table has rows missing from the RIGHT table then LEFT JOIN will be slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original query looks queer. Why do you cross join products and sale_products?

It should better be:

```
select sp.saleid, p.name as product, c.name as category
from sale_products sp
join products p on p.productid = sp.productid
join categories c on c.categoryid = p.categoryid;
```

This is the straight-forward way to show the data. You *can* use subqueries instead, but I see no sense in it:

```
select 
  sp.saleid
  (
    select p.name
    from products p
    where p.productid = sp.productid
  ) as product, 
  (
    select c.name
    from categories c 
    where c.categoryid = p.categoryid
  ) as category
from sale_products sp;
```

Here is yet another query with subqueries. Again without any benefit over the simple query using direct joins on the tables.

```
select sp.saleid, p.name as product, c.name as category
from sale_products sp
join (select productid, name from products) p on p.productid = sp.productid
join (select categoryid, name from categories) c on c.categoryid = p.categoryid;
```

Comment: Why do you cross join products and sale_products? Because categories table contains less data than products and products table less than sale_products. So, joining among categories and products then with sale_products. It is bit faster than first join sale_products with products.

Comment: No. You are trying to somewhat force the DBMS to execute your query in the way you consider best. If it strictly *did* follow, it would join *every* record in products with *every* record in sale_products, thus creating a huge intermediate result, (this is what a cross join does) and only later remove records where the productID doesn't match. Don't try to outsmart the DBMS; you only obfuscate the query and even make it harder for the DBMS to find the optimal execution plan.

Comment: I am confused.

Let there are 20 customers, 100 sales, and 300 volumes sold. Therefore, the result from that join will be at least
300 rows long. Those 300 rows must be joined to the 20 rows in customer. However, if we reverse the order, then the 20 rows
in customer are joined to 100 rows in sale, producing a table of
100 rows, which can then be joined to volume. In either case,
we are stuck with a join of 100 rows to 300 rows, but when the
customer table is handled first, the other join is 20 to 100 rows,
rather than 20 to 300 rows.  -- SQL clearly explained by JAN L. HARRINGTON

Comment: You are thinking too technical, thus trying to do the DBMS' task. Don't do that. Make your queries as simple as possible, telling the DBMS *what* to do, not *how* to do it. It is the DBMS' task to decide whether to join the smallest table first or not. It will certainly put its row count consideration, but probably also its record size, total file size and file fragmentation, available indexes and appropriate join techniques etc. Most likely the DBMS does this job better then you, so let it do it.

Comment: Ok, I understand. You mean DBMS software has its own optimizer.